# Need to create unique checkboxes on the fly in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a json object what has rows of songs. I want to associate and manage a set of checkboxes along with each row in a table I am generating for this object. So far I have:

```
<tr ng-repeat="dataline in data | filter:query">
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="sheLikes(dataline.filename)"> 
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="heLikes(dataline.filename)">
<td>{{dataline.artist}}</td><td>{{dataline.title}}</td>
<td>{{dataline.album}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to load a set of checks into the rows that aren't saved in the database that contains the music data. So I want each checkbox addressable. I assume I can do this with ng-model but I can't figure out how. Any advice would be appreciated....

Comment: what determines *"not saved in database"*? What does a `dataline ` object look like? Not difficult to `ng-model` properties of those objects

Comment: you bind the `ngModel` of the checkbox like this: `ng-model="deadline.isChecked"` and in your controller you can access it by `$scope.data[0].isChecked` (Note that `0` is just an example)